# Retrieve local and heroku application hostname outside a request

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I have to configure one of the module in my application and give it a specific URL, based on the hostname. Something like `http://localhost` locally and `http://myapp.herokuapp.com`. I know I can just hardcode the value depending on `NODE_ENV`, or even store it as an environment value and use `process.env.CUSTOMVAR_HOSTNAME`. But somehow it feels wrong, since `myapp` is already configured in the Heroku admin panel. And I can't use `request.headers.host` since the module configuration happens at the start of the application, before any request can be handled.

Is there a way to retrieve the Heroku application name from the code ? Or from an environment variable ? I want my code to stay the same whether I'm executing code locally or on Heroku (or any other place actually).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't find any way, so I created a local variable `hostname` based on NODE_ENV (`development` or `production`) with the proper hostname value.